# How can I program a pygame to not run something repeatedly if the user clicks and holds on something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to code a python - pygame, where if the user clicks on a rectangle, then it will change color. However, if the user clicks and holds on the rectangle, then it will not change colors repeatedly, but rather only once.

Comment: Are you reacting to MOUSEBUTTONUP or MOUSEBUTTONDOWN?

Comment: Okay, so. Do I understand correctly that you tried writing some code, but when you try to run the program the rectangle changes colours repeatedly, which is not what you want? Then you should a) say so explicitly, b) **show the code that you tried to use**, and c) explain what you think is preventing you from fixing it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #check if the mouse click is within the rectangle
        #position is event.pos
        changeRectColor()
```

This should do it.

Check out https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get for more info

Comment: If you want to make it only change when you left click check event.button. 1 is left click, 2 is middle click, 3 is right click, 4 is scroll up, and 5 is scroll down.